# How to identify same elements uniquely in AngularJS using protractor

Tags: protractor

I have two buttons with the same name as 'select node' which is placed side by side. I am able to click on one of the 'Select node' button but for the other i am not able to identify the element uniquely.

Could you please help me in identifying the other element which has the same button name?

Comment: Could you please paste the html for the buttons?

Comment: I am sorry due to security reasons I cannot paste the html for the buttons but the scenario is something like below:

Comment: The functionality is I need to merge two statements (financial statements). 

1. First I select two statements Statement 1 and Statement 2 from the data grid

2. Secondly, on the basis of the selection of the above two statements, it displays two buttons, one button for the first statement and the second button for the second one.

It actually generates a dynamic number and gets appended to the Button ID which is generated after the selection of the statements

How do I approach this?

Comment: it is a multi-select tree., and a dynamic number gets appended to the multi-select tree id such as node_12, or node_1 based on the selected statement

Answer (score 0):

Using `element.all(by.css());` could potentially solve your issue, although it is hard to know for sure without the html. For example:

```
var buttons = element.all(by.css('button_selector'));
var button1 = buttons.first();
var button2 = buttons.last();
```